# how to add / configure new currency in sitecore commerce 9.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Please suggest me How to add new currency in existing currency sets ? actually i'm adding new currency but it will be not binding at business tool currency dropdown.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just defined the currency set and you didn't follow all steps like here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/configure-currencies.html

You need to **Define currency setting**s:

1.In the Content Editor, navigate to storefront in the Commerce Control Panel (sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/).

2. Expand the storefront. right-click Currencies Display Adjustments, and select Insert, Currency.
3. Type a name for the currency and click OK.

On the Content tab, define:

- Currency Description–provide an meaningful description of the
  currency.
- Currency Symbol–the three-digit ISO code or special character, for
  example USD or $.
- Currency Symbol Position–select 0 to display $n, 1 to display n$, 2
  to display $n, and 3 to display n $
- Currency Number Format–type the culture code for the currency. For
  example:

  1. ja - Japanese
  2. fr - French (France)
  3. da - Danish
  4. en-GB - English (Great Britain)
  5. en-US - English (United States)

Click Save.

You need to **Associate a currency set with a storefront**

1. In the Content Editor, navigate to sitecore/Commerce/Commerce
   Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/.
2. Select Currency Configuration.
3. On the Content tab, in the Commerce Control Panel section, select
   the currency set you want to associate with the storefront.
4. Save your changes.